# $A^3\cdot B^3=X^3+Y^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Prove that if $A,B\in M_n (\mathbb {C}) $ then there exists $X,Y \in M_n (\mathbb {C}) $ s.t. $A^3\cdot B^3=X^3+Y^3$.

If $A,B $ commutes then it's clear. But what about the other case?

Comment: What proof did you use for the commuting case?

Comment: @rschwieb:  Let $X = AB$ and $Y = 0$.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to find it, but it seems every matrix is a cube, and every matrix is the sum of two cubes; certainly if you are allowing $\mathbb C$

Comment: @WillJagy Not every matrix is a cube.  For example, $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ is not.

Comment: However, every nonsingular square matrix is a cube (use the holomorphic functional calculus with a branch of $z^{1/3}$), and every square matrix is the sum of two nonsingular matrices.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh :)

Comment: Beware that this could be a contest problem. Someone posted the same question a few days ago with the [tag:contest-math] tag. I gave an answer and deleted it immediately after I noticed that tag. I asked the asker of that question whether the contest was an ongoing one, he/she didn't reply but deleted the question right away.

Comment: @user1551 Do you have a link to the deleted question?  You may want to flag this question and include the link so the mods can decide what to do.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks, I see what you mean. This was a part memory from a previous, very similar, post, within the past week or two.

Comment: **Update.** It turns out that the question I mentioned was also [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557732) by the same user, but the statement is a bit different: it asks to show the existence of $X,Y$ such that $(A^3+B^3)(C^3+D^3)=X^3+Y^3$. The question here per se does not lead to a solution of that one, but some comments in the above have already pointed out how that earlier question can be solved.

Comment: @user1551 I deleted the question because I want to think myself, but I didn't suceed to solve it. I found it in a book and it hasn't solution. I have doubts about its conclusion. I realise that I have no idea how I can prove the toy case so I post it again.